# How to find the volume of a solid between $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$, and $z=0$ above the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=2y$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

*Find the volume of the solid which is between the paraboloid $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$, and $z=0$ above the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=2y$.*

**Solution:**

The first thing I did was the graph of $x^{2}+y^{2}=2y$:

[image: x^{2}+y^{2}=2y]

And then,

$$0\ \leqslant\ z\ \leqslant\ x^{2}+y^{2}$$

$$0\ \leqslant\ \theta\ \leqslant\ 2\pi$$

$$0\ \leqslant\ r\ \leqslant\ 2$$

Then, I tried to define the triple integral as:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{r^{2}}r\ dzdrd\theta$$

Is that correct, i.e., the way I have defined the limites of each iterated integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the circle is not centered at (0,0), you can't describe the limits like that. I think that the best approach is this. Let D be the projection of the solidus in xOy plane (blue circle).

[image]

The solidus we want to calculate the volume is below the red surface and over the blue circle.

$$
V=\iint_D{x^2+y^2}\,dA
$$

We can describe D as follow:

$$
\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\theta) \\
y=1+r\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}\quad 0\leq r \leq 1, 0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi
$$

The last **r** bellow, is due to polar form.
$$
V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1{((r\cos(\theta))^2+(1+r\sin(\theta))^2)r}\,dr\,d\theta
$$
$$
V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1{r+r^3+2r^2\sin(\theta)}\,dr\,d\theta
$$

$$V=\dfrac{3\pi}{2} v.u.$$

Comment: $V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1{r+r^3+2r^2\sin(\theta)}\,dr\,d\theta$

Comment: @InfZero, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square you get;

$$x^2+y^2 - 2y = 0 \iff x^2+y^2-2y+1 = 1 \iff x^2+(y-1)^2 = 1$$

i.e the radius has range $0 \leq r \leq 1$. There are no points of distance $2$ in the circle of radius $1$ about $(0,1)$. Also, as @Alexandre points out, $x,y$ are in your domain $D$. So you need to have $x,y$ expressed in a way that distinguishes from computing the integral when the circle is centered at the origin i.e $x = t \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$. Use the equation $x^2+(y-1)^2 = 1$ to get $x,y$ in polar coordinates i.e

$$x = r \cos \theta \Rightarrow y = \sqrt{1-r^2 \cos^2 \theta} + 1 = r \sin \theta + 1$$

Comment: That's right! Thanks!

Comment: Once the limit for $r$ is made, the triple integral is OK? Thanks?